# What control can I use to create something like facebook favorites edit screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, user-interface, user-controls

I want to create a control which behaves like facebook favorites edit screen (see image). I am working on ASP.NET

Thanks

[image: Sample facebook favorites window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create this functionality will require considerable javacript/jQuery and AJAX skills. You can use the new ASP.NET WebAPI to achieve much of the back-end functionality.

If you have those skills - please be more specific about what you need help with.

If not, your best bet is to trawl the websites of component frameworks and vendors, such as jQueryUI, Infragistics, Telerik and so on. I doubt you will find anything that does everything.

Instead, break it down into smaller parts. Start with the autocomplete search box. Then you could use something like knockoutjs to display the list of favourites below it. Then use jQuery to add functionality like removing a favourite.

Finally - test thoroughly across all browsers!